# vue-material: show floating-action-button / speed-dial only on small screens

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

So I'm using vue in combination with [vue-material](https://vuematerial.io/)

I have the following speed dial defined:

```
<template>
  <md-speed-dial class="md-top-right" md-direction="bottom" md-event="click">
      <md-speed-dial-target class="md-primary">
        <md-icon class="md-morph-initial">add</md-icon>
        <md-icon class="md-morph-final">close</md-icon>
      </md-speed-dial-target>

      <md-speed-dial-content>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon>directions</md-icon>
        </md-button>

        <md-button class="md-icon-button">
          <md-icon>streetview</md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </md-speed-dial-content>
    </md-speed-dial>
</template>
```

How can I show it only on small screens?

I tried adding the classes `md-xlarge-hide md-large-hide md-medium-hide` to the root `md-speed-dial` tag, but this didn't work because it gets overridden by the component css of `md-speed-dial`. I also tried wrapping the component in a `div` with the mentioned classes, but this didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

the class can be overridden because it's not mark with `!important`. See https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/dev/dist/vue-material.min.css

You can add `!important` to these classes to make them harder to override (either globally or on this component only).

```
.md-hide {
    display: none !important
  }

  @media (min-width:1904px) {
    .md-xlarge-hide {
      display: none !important
    }
  }

  @media (max-width:1903px) {
    .md-large-hide {
      display: none !important
    }
  }

  @media (max-width:1264px) {
    .md-medium-hide {
      display: none !important
    }
  }

  @media (max-width:944px) {
    .md-small-hide {
      display: none !important
    }
  }

  @media (max-width:600px) {
    .md-xsmall-hide {
      display: none !important
    }
  }
```

**Method 2**

use `v-show` to control the display. Example:

```
<div v-show="window.screen.width<768">example</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/4kg2ndkb/2/

Comment: Thanks for you response. I see, there is no way of doing this only with the existing css classes hm? Guess I try method 2 then.